# Do we need parenthesis in lim?

Tags: limits, notation

Is  $\lim_{x\to 0} x+x^2=(\lim_{x\to 0} x)+x^2=0+x^2=x^2$ or $\lim_{x\to 0} x+x^2=\lim_{x\to 0} (x+x^2)=0+0^2=0$?

Comment: Good question. [These lists](http://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/lHopital/limit_laws.html) are written with parentheses avoided as much as possible, as if $\lim$ were an operator of lowest thinkable precedence. Then again, under that premise one *should* write $(\lim a_n)\lim b_n$. Or maybe it is common sense to interprete things in a way that does not make use of legal but weird usega of bound vs. free varaibles ...

Comment: It depends on what you are doing. If you are given $f(x) + g(x) = h(x)$ and you want to take $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}$ both sides, then you end up with $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} (f(x) + g(x)) =  \lim\limits_{x \to 0} h(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} (f(x) + g(x)) = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x) + \lim\limits_{x \to 0} g(x)$, provided they exists.

Comment: As it is stated in the link of Hagen von Eitzen: $\lim_{x \to 0} x+x^2=\lim_{x \to 0} x+\lim_{x \to 0} x^2=0+0=0$. Paranteses are not necessary.

Comment: It’s intended to be interpreted the second way, and in most cases context will make this clear. However, I strongly disagree with @callculus: omitting the parentheses is poor practice. It’s much better to write $$\lim_{x\to 0}(x+x^2)$$ and avoid the possible ambiguity.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I don´t see a problem by ommitting the parantheses. If the limit does not apply to $x^2$ then I would say that parantheses are necessary: $$\lim_{x\to 0} (x)+x^2=0+x^2=x^2$$

Comment: @callculus: Even if I adopted your convention, which I consider profoundly unnatural, I would not accept what you’ve just written: it would have to be $$\left(\lim_{x\to 0}x\right)+x^2\;.$$ In any case, the problem with omitting the parentheses is evident in the fact that people have to ask how the expression is to be interpreted. The OP is far from the first to be uncertain.